# gcc - enforce omiting frame pointers for specific functions

Tags: c, gcc, x86

I am writing a bit of low-level code in C using gcc and I have to write a function that moves the stack. That in itself is pretty straight-forward. However while changing the stack-pointer to the new stack is easy, changing all frame-pointers of functions in the calling-chain is impossible. If these functions would rely on frame pointers to access local variables or arguments after the stack has been moved, they would access completely wrong memory addresses. Therefor these (rather simple functions) should just use the stack-pointer for these purposes.

In order to accomplish this, I tried adding the option `-fomit-frame-pointer` which should not "keep the frame pointer in a register for functions that don't need one", according to the gcc manual. For some functions this works rather nicely, for example:

```
size_t get_stack_size( u32 stack_start ) {
    u32 stack_current;
    asm(
        "movl %%esp,%%edx\n"
        :"=d"(stack_current)
    );
    return stack_start - stack_current;
}
```

Turns into:

```
00000000 <get_stack_size>:
   0:   8b 44 24 04             mov    0x4(%esp),%eax
   4:   89 e2                   mov    %esp,%edx
   6:   29 d0                   sub    %edx,%eax
   8:   c3                      ret
```

Very nice, no frame pointers here.
However, another very simple function:

```
void k_main() {
    init_video();
    k_info( 0, "\nLoading..." );
    sys_init();
    k_info( 0, "Start-up complete" );   
    for(;;);
}
```

Turns into this mess:

```
00000000 <k_main>:
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
   6:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   7 <k_main+0x7>
   b:   52                      push   %edx
   c:   52                      push   %edx
   d:   68 00 00 00 00          push   $0x0
  12:   6a 00                   push   $0x0
  14:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   15 <k_main+0x15>
  19:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   1a <k_main+0x1a>
  1e:   59                      pop    %ecx
  1f:   58                      pop    %eax
  20:   68 0c 00 00 00          push   $0xc
  25:   6a 00                   push   $0x0
  27:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   28 <k_main+0x28>
  2c:   83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
  2f:   eb fe                   jmp    2f <k_main+0x2f>
```

Numerous things I do not understand here:

1. Why are 8 bytes of local variable stack required?
2. Which purpose does pushing edx twice serve?
3. Why does it remove 16 bytes from the stack before the loop when there is 24 bytes on it and the instruction doesn't do anything useful anyways?
4. And the most important one: Why is a frame pointer required in this function?

How can I get gcc to not use stack-pointers in functions like this? In this specific function it actually is not an issue because the value of the stack-pointer is never used (which makes you wonder even more why it wasted instructions on creating one anyways), but in other functions or later when I modify `k_main()` it could become one. Is there maybe an `__attribute__(())` or something that forces gcc to not set up a frame-pointer for this function or throw an error when that is not possible? Is the behaviour shown above a bug in gcc?

Edit: The entire flags for gcc are `CC_FLAGS := -std=gnu99 -Os -m32 -march=i386 -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector`, in case that helps.

Comment: According to the output of http://gcc.godbolt.org/ it seems to be a 4.8 issue. 4.9 or older ones like 4.7 omit it.

Comment: I'm not quite following you, are you proposing to relocate the stack for an already created frame as opposed to temporarily switching it out in a leaf function? If so then frame pointers are hardly the only pointers commonly taken out to variables on the stack. How do propose to patch up the rest of them?

Comment: @doynax Which other pointers would I have to change except for frame-pointers? Data is either saved on the stack or in the .data section and since I am not using heap-memory before this everything should be okay.

Comment: @Max Benson: As I said, I may be misunderstanding you, but you wrote about wanting to recursively move the stack along the entire call chain. If so, them how would you relocate a pointer taken to a buffer on the old stack and stored somewhere else on the stack or data segment? That is, much as the frame pointers do.

Comment: @doynax Oh now I understand what you mean. If I had a buffer on the stack and would then reference it with a pointer it would of course also have to change. Luckily I know every bit of C-code that is running since I am not using standard libraries and nothing like that happens. So that is not an issue. The scenario is simply that this program boots on the machine and one of the first things it should to is move the stack. However it needs to call a few functions beforehand to find a suitable position in memory for the stack. Therefor I wanna be sure it doesnt mess with frame pointers.

Comment: @Max Benson: I see, that should work. I fear a solution relying on being able to coax the compiler into generating a specific code sequence will always be rather brittle. If you control the code and it is relatively simple then I recommend that you instead try re-structuring the flow to abandon the old stack frames altogether, invoking a new top-level function while switching stacks.